# Backup SP Online lists with attachments - maybe powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup, attachments

Earlier in on-premises I used stsadm or powershell export-web/import-web to backup webs and particular lists/libraries. Now in cloud afaik we have only list templates (which are often useless because of '50 Mb threshold restriction'), and expensive third-party tools.

I also used [PnP-Provision Framework](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2019/06/16/how-to-migrate-content-with-pnp-provisioning-engine/) (powershell) to clone webs, but it can copy lists/libs schema but not data.

Maybe there are some new powershell scripts to backup data; what do You use? It is strange that we now have commands to work with Flows, but still cannot simply backup production data..

Best regards, Gennady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could backup/copy all items including attachments to another list using **MS Flow**.

**Please the following steps:**

**Step1 Create New List**

Create a new list and add the corresponding columns in the new list. If set JSON Formattings for some columns, please copy it to the corresponding new list columns in advance.

[image]

**Step2 Create A MS Flow**

1. Add a **manual trigger**, then add a **SharePoint-Get items** action
2. Add the first **Apply to each**, within it, add **SharePoint-Get Attachments** action, specify the Item ID from the Get items action
3. After that, add a **Create item** action, which is used to create item on new list.
4. Add the second **Apply to each**, specify the **Get Attachments body** as the Input, then add the **Get Attachment content** action, Id Choose ID from the Get items action, File Identifier choose Id from Get Attachments action
5. After that, add an **Add attachment** action, Id choose from the Create item action, File Name choose DisplayName from Get Attachments action, File Content choose Attachment Content from the Get Attachment content action

[image]

**Step3 Save & Test Flow**

**Step4 Go to the new list, you will see the following screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thank You EchoDu_MSFT! Nobody wants to share their own solutions to backup lists, as I understand.. :-D  So Your approach is not very scalable but best solution for now, thank You much for detailed instruction and for Your time! Best regards, Gennady

Comment: Hi, Gennady G. Thanks for your reply. If there is any solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank You much @EchoDu_MSFT!)